# Phone won't boot/start after successful flashing through QFIL

Tags: adb, rom-flashing, recovery-mode, fastboot, unbricking

My phone was bricked, so I decided to flash my phone LYF f1s with the stock ROM through QFIL, but after after successful flashing it won't start !! Nothing happens, no matter which combination of volume and power buttons I press, only the charging light blinks or keep flashing when I connect it to my charger or laptop. Please help !!

Comment: Does it still detected as `hs-usb qdloader 9008`  in the Device Manager ? (Windows)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like some of the images are incorrect for your phone?
or maybe you can try to remove the battery, then put it back and try again.

Answer (score 0):

You can take the battery out, plug in the charger, ad see if the phone can at least give an unable to charge error.

Answer (score -1):

Just unplug your battery and wait for 5 to 10 min until phone get back to its normal temperature. Then plug the battery as it was earlier and start your phone.